# Linear approximation

Tags: python, numpy

I want to perform a linear approximation and get the linear equation of my data from the array of data in python. I was thinking about using:

```py
np.polyfit(x,y,1).
```

But the problem is that my equation is

```py
y=ax+b, b=0
```

So I need to calculate only parameter a. Can you suggest something?

Comment: If all you need is a linear approximation where `b=0`, you can just derive the formula for least-squares and find a = sum(x_i * y_i) / sum(x_i ^2)

Comment: Alternatively, you can use SKLearn, which allows you to define the constant term in the regression to be zero: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for called `Linear Regression`, take a look at [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linear-regression-python-implementation/) for more description.